# I need to make a list for all motherboard attributes

Tags: motherboard, desktop-computer

I am trying to make a list of all attributes that pc motherboards have (I need this for database).
Here what I got so far:

- Model
- FormFactor
- CpuSocket
- Chipset
- MemorySlots
- MemoryType
- MaxMemory
- RaidSupport
- OnBoardVideo
- CrossFireSupport
- SliSupport
- OnboardEthernet
- OnboardUsb3.0

Am I miss some important attribute? If I am please tell me what I have missed.

Comment: What do you want the classification for? You might classify according to CPUs supported, chipset, and _lots_ of other characteristics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by others, the list is huge, and the quickest way to do it is to start somewhere. Pick one, randomly or the one you are using, and visit your manufacture website, select your motherboard model, then click *specification*, it should list all its attributes. Record all, then build on that.

An example ..

- Manufacture
- Model
- BIOS (make, model, version)
- Form Factor
- CPU support (socket)
- Front Side Bus
- Chipset
- Memory (type, slots, max)
- On Board

  - Audio
  - Video
  - LAN
- Storage Interface (ide, sata)
- Expansion Slots (pci, agp, pci express)
- USB (version, ports)
- Connectors (serial, parallel, ps/2)
- Extras (for anything else that is unique to a specific motherboard)

Start with motherboards you are most likely to work with in your database. Not only this will help you start building your database quickly, but will make it more accurate, as you will not add an attribute you don't need, or forget to include one you need.

Comment: Thanks. As question is closed I accepted your answer. It seam's that I have to study a lot of boards to fill my list :)

Answer (score 3):

I think that you could refer to a freeware program called CPUID that shows all this informations once installed and executed on a machine.
If you just need a list you can copy fields from it.
Its freeware and you can get it here:
http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

Answer (score 2):

There is huge and ever changing list I am not sure that you could exhaustively list all of them. I can name several off the top of my head

- expansion slots, pci, pci-e, agp, isa, etc
- USB headers, internal and external
- FireWire
- thunderbolt
- SATA, eSATA
- IDE, EIDE
- Bios, type model, etc

It really depends wildly on your expected usage.

Answer (score 2):

Try [AIDA64](http://www.aida64.com/downloads/a64xe), the successor to Everest Ultimate.

I always found the free version of Everest provided all the information I needed- so hopefully the same can be said for this product.

Comment: I read the question as - what could attributes be in general pertaining to a motherboard. I could be wrong, but question does not sound like finding out what is connected to "this" board.:)      But good suggestion on AIDA64 for local board info.

Comment: I misread it- you're quite right. I didn't realize the OP was asking such an open-ended question.

Answer (score 1):

- Power connectors, 20+4 and 4 or 6 or 8
- Pci e x4. x8 x16
- SATA I, II or III (quantity of each)
- CPU support technology - Supports Intel Turbo Boost 2.0 Technology,
  Supports Hyper-Threading,Technology Supports Untied Overclocking
  Technology
- Audio chipset
- S/PDIF out
- Dual/Quad channel support (memory)
- 1.44 Floppy drive (old technology, but some AM2, AM# boards still have connections for them)